# Use SegmentedControl to switch between views

Tags: swiftui

I have the implementation as follow

```
    struct DealsScreen: View {
    @State var selectedSegment = "list"

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
            HStack{
                Spacer()
            }
            Picker("", selection: $selectedSegment){
                Text("List").tag("list")
                Text("Map").tag("map")
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(1)
            Spacer()


            self.selectedSegment == "list" ? ListContainer() : MapContainer()



        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to display a different container when the selected segmentedControl item changes.
How can I do it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, this will work after i change

```
self.selectedSegment == "list" ? ListContainer() : MapContainer()
```

to

```
if self.selectedSegment == "list" {
                ListContainer()
            }
            else {
                MapContainer()
            }
```